# Manga about a princess who fell out of her cradle as a baby and broke all her bones

Tags: story-identification, magic, manga

I read a manga about a princess who was born. She gets out of her cradle and falls, breaking all her bones. If I remember correctly, a mage fixed all her bones in a really painful way. I cannot remember how she got in a coma, but she lost her ice power to protect her from getting poisoned.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Was this in full colour or mostly black & white? Also, what colour was the princess' hair?