# Manhwa where the female lead is found by her family again after her mother dies

Tags: story-identification, manga

The female lead has been reborn a lot, as well as seeing her dead mom alive and then dying. The father is a man with black hair and she has 2 siblings; a girl and a boy with black hair and yellow eyes. The girl can summon the spirt of the moon as a butterfly and the sun as a snake. Her family has black hair with yellow eyes like a tiger.

The father meets the daughter after the child was brought by family friends, I think. The siblings meet her later.

She is scared of the stuff in her room and of the people. Such as the bathtub scene and where she eats, which is on the ground.

Later the fathers brother her uncle and her moms friend the king was someone she met multiples time. So when he sent a letter with gift she called the king by his name which only a few knew/spoke of. The family was confused as they didn't know how she knew.

Also the doctor she had was a lady who grew close to her as they aged and in the ending the doctor left to start her own clinic.

Also the moon healed her injuries where she had many broken bones all over her body in a instant.

The manhwa was updated recently showing her all group to few years older child/teen and her siblings were either teens/adults.

Answer (score 1):

This may be *[Everything's Coming Up Roses](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/everythings-coming-up-roses)*, also identified [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267133).

> Abducted from her mother at a young age and tortured for her incredible power, Evanna knew nothing but agony her whole life. That is until one day, she is rescued and returned to the father she never knew, the Duke of Vicente. But as Evanna’s very existence brings back painful memories for the Duke, he must learn how to love her, while Evanna must come to trust her father and heal her trauma. But with Evanna's power highly coveted, can these two overcome their thorny pasts for a rosier future?

The protagonist was tortured and sacrificed by people that wanted her powers, and she goes back in time after dying. After reincarnating her mother is alive again, but dies shortly after in a repeat of the initial events.

This time she is rescued by her father - the father and his other son and daughter all have black hair and golden eyes. The father has slit pupils, like a cat or tiger, but the other children did not inherit this special trait.

[image]

She is traumatized after being rescued by her father due to the events of her first life; the majority of the series deals with her rehabilitation.

I can't confirm the details of the spirits, the specific details of her trauma, the ending, or the meeting with the king. Mangaupdates has it tagged with "spirit/s", so spirits will have some appearance in the story.

Comment: The mention of broken bones made me think it might be the same story as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/267586, but from skimming this I doubt it.